# React JS Child to parent props passing Example not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

App.js file:-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./components/Child";

function App() {
  const [childDetails, setData] = useState({
    name: "?",
    email: "?",
  });

  // Call back function from parent to child component that returns some value; we can directly use `that value to update the data inside the parent component.
  const sendBackData = (childDetails) => {
    setData(childDetails);
    console.log(childDetails); // To view this object's "name" & "email" values in the console `window, after submitting.
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>
        Example illustrating "Passing Data from Child component to Parent
        component".
      </h2>

      {/* Sending the call-back function from parent to child. */}
      <Child sendDataHandler={sendBackData} />

      <div>
        The following is the data sent from Child component :<br />
        <h4>
          Name:
          <span style={{ color: "blue" }}>{childDetails.name}</span>
          <br />
          Email ID:
          <span style={{ color: "magenta" }}>{childDetails.email}</span>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Child.js File:-

```
import React from "react";

class Child extends React.Component {
  onTrigger = (event) => {
    this.props.sendDataHandler(event.target.myname.value);
    this.props.sendDataHandler(event.target.myemail.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* Form used with an 'input' box & a submit 'button' */}
        <form onSubmit={this.onTrigger}>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <input type="text" name="myname" placeholder="Enter Name" />
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <input type="text" name="myemail" placeholder="Enter Email" />
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <input // Now we create an input-type "submit" button.
            type="submit"
            value="Submit" // Text to be displayed over this input-type "submit" button.
            style={{ backgroundColor: "magenta" }} // Additional Styling done to the 'submit' `button.
          />
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Child;
```

I am trying to get an output as:

(Enter the following in the input boxes)
Name: Bala
Email: bala@gmail.com

The following is the data sent from Child component :
Name:Bala
Email ID:bala@gmail.com`

Comment: Can you create a Codesandbox link, so that it could be updated there itself?

Comment: eloborate the problem  specify the problem correctly . provide more details

Comment: Try this, very short one,  Codesanbox link -> https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-tree-88xdp2

Answer (score 0):

The `onTrigger` should send object rather than string.

```
  onTrigger = (event) => {
   let formData={
   name:event.target.myname.value,
   email: event.target.myemail.value
    }
    this.props.sendDataHandler(formData);
    //this.props.sendDataHandler();
    event.preventDefault();
  };
```